# Como dizer obrigado em respostas?

Tags: debate, proposta-para-faq, comportamento

Um forte preditor de uma resposta má qualidade pode surpreendê-lo: a presença das palavras obrigado ou obrigada em uma resposta curta.

Isso mesmo, o humilde e inocente desejo de agradecer seu companheiro (ou companheira) por alguma pergunta ou resposta que eles contribuíram acaba, infelizmente, sufocando nosso sistema em milhares e milhares de "respostas" floridas *obrigado*.

[image: Obrigada]

Não há nada de errado com o sentimento, mas temos uma convenção firmemente estabelecida já em vigor para agradecer aos nossos colegas usuários: **votar a sua postagem ou comentário!** Cada voto favorável é um implícito "obrigado" .

[image: Voto]

Mas, para ser justo, é preciso uma conta registrada e um mínimo de 15 pontos de reputação antes de ganhar o direito de dar o *upvote*. Então legiões de *obrigado* vindos de usuários anônimos são postados.

Há uma maneira muito melhor de agradecer a seus colegas por ajudar você, mesmo para usuários totalmente anônimos. Se você encontrou uma resposta incrível em um site do Stack Exchange e quer agradecer-nos - faça-o **contribuindo e ajudando a responder uma pergunta de outra pessoa!** Isso é exatamente o modelo de pares ajudando colegas que fundaram a rede em: pagá-lo para a frente.

É educado dizer obrigado. Mas **retribuir e contribuir para a comunidade no que é mais importante para ela é uma forma mais construtiva de agradecimento**. Nós nunca vamos mudar o mundo, mas com certeza podemos melhorar o nosso cantinho, mesmo que apenas um pouco - e que nos obriga a contribuir mais do que um simples "obrigado".

---

Texto parcialmente baseado em [How to Say Thanks in an Answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/how-to-say-thanks-in-an-answer/).

---

[Retorne para o índice da FAQ](/q/699)

Answer (score 12):

EMHO (o mesmo que IMHO) no SO, devemos agradecer pontuando positivamente as respostas, assim como pontuamos quem fez uma pergunta bacana, que possa nos ajudar agora ou no futuro.

Quando faço uma resposta, não espero ouvir um obrigado. Já estou acostumado. Mas quando recebo pontos positivos por ela, isso me deixa bastante feliz. Pra mim significa que não estou falando besteira e que os outros reconhecem o meu esforço.

É a assim que funciona o StackExchange.

**Gente, é tão bacana escrever em Português no SO! Não tô acreditando. E olha que eu já peço isso pra eles há anos!**

Answer (score -1):

Concordo que pontuar uma resposta é uma forma de agradecer pela ajuda, mas ao meu ver, ter apenas essa opção de agradecimento deixa a interação com a comunidade meio fria.

As vezes apenas pontuar não é suficiente para dizer o quanto uma resposta contribuiu. Não sei se é uma questão cultural, mas aqui no Brasil estamos acostumados a agradecer de forma mais pessoal. Acho válido agradecer uma boa resposta com um comentário.

Comment: Não vejo problemas se isso não for a regra, e sim uma exceção. Eu mesmo faço isso de vez em quando. Tenha em vista que a) comentários são cidadãos de segunda classe no site, e podem ser apagados sem aviso a qualquer momento; e b) se você *sempre* agradece em comentários (e se o comentário consiste somente disso), seu próprio efeito acaba anulado; imagine se toda resposta tivesse um "obrigado" embaixo – vale [o mesmo que eu já disse para saudações em agradecimentos em perguntas](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/851/74).

Comment: Foi como eu disse, quando a solução apresentada é genial, apenas pontuar as vezes não é suficiente, e alguns usuários sentem a necessidade em dizer obrigado. Não disse que escrever obrigado tenha que ser regra, mas não vejo sentido impor apenas a pontuação como forma de agradecimento.

Comment: Concordo com você, embora não ache que isso esteja tão claro na sua resposta. Pode parecer que você está defendendo um uso indiscriminado de agradecimentos em comentários, o que pode gerar muita sujeita neles.

Comment: Não estou defendendo o uso indiscriminado, só o direito de uso quando o usuário se sente na vontade diante a qualidade da solução.